# how to pass event and variable as argument

Tags: jquery

In the following code, When I click anywhere on the document I am removing particular div's highlights class.

I have different class names for different div's for that, I am writing different functions for each and every div.

I want to write it using only one function by passing as arguments to a function parameter. But here I am facing the real problem. I have 'e'(event) on document.click and the variable 'clicked'.

I don't know how to pass the 'e' and the variable 'clicked' as an argument. Please help me with solving this.

```
 $(document).click(function(e) {
      var clicked = $(e.target);
        if(!clicked.parents().hasClass("highlight"))
        {
            $(".highlight").removeClass("highlights");
        }
 });
```

I want to do it as something like this:

```
function clickFun(parameters to be passed)
{

}
$(document).click(function()
{
  clickFun(args to be passed);
}
```

As you can see I wanna pass arguments to a function parameter. Please help me with solving this.

Comment: $(document).click(function(e)
{
   clickFun(e);
}

Comment: Please format you code properly and post your html code for better response. link: http://www.jsonwrapper.com/?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=tags&utm_campaign=queries

Comment: `highlight !==highlights`. check once

Answer (score 0):

Do like this way:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).click(function(){
        clickFun($(this)); //Function calling
    });
    function clickFun(event){
         console.log(event);// Your code 
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: this code is not working. I am getting an error as e is not defined.

Comment: $(this) is a better way to get current target event